# Suitable object for pstPlanePut?

Tags: pstricks

I want to rotate lines and text in 3d space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\pstPlanePut[plane=yz](0,0,0){ASDF

FDSA}
\end{document}
```

Causes latex to complain:

```
Runaway argument?
{ASDF
! Paragraph ended before \pst@PlanePut was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
```

Without the paragraph, no error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\pstPlanePut[plane=yz](0,0,0){ASDF FDSA}
\end{document}
```

I am unclear on the restrictions concerning pscustom, which was my first thought. But, I get the same error wrapping the paragraphs in pscustom or psframebox.

Is there a way to create a graphics object that is a suitable parameter for pstPlanePut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you box the content it is fine. As such, I'd suggest something like a `tabular` (or similar, `\parbox`, `\minipage`, ...):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\pstPlanePut[plane=yz](0,0,0){\begin{tabular}{l} ASDF \\ FDSA \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Depending on what you're after, you may have to fiddle with the anchor of the box.